# TFS Apply Label what to do after getting an earlier label

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Let's say I `Get This Version` of a TFS apply label created much earlier time. I know I can build and run it and review the code. But, what else can I do? I mean if I make changes to the code, what happens if I check it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to make changes to such code, you will most likely have to resolve conflicts that arise from the fact that the code has changed since the version you have loaded into your workspace. Best case scenario, the code will be auto-merge for you without conflicts, but you still need to review the changes to make sure the merge is done correctly. It really depends on how the code got changed since that version.